# How to remove space on right side of div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a column structure with bootstrap 4 . It looks something like this it has 1 row with 2 columns:

```
  <div class="left">
        <hr class="container hline">
        <div id="main" class="container border">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 top">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 top">
                /*Widget with too much margin right*/
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is that the widget on the right has too much empty space. The columns have an equal length (col-lg-5) but there is still a lot of space on the right. How can I remove this and keep the columns the same size?

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/bertie2017/pen/aaxqMQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use columns within your rows, and the columns are based on a 12 column grid. You currently have 10 columns worth of width taken up using 2 `.col-5` column and you also have a pixel for the divider that is stuck into the row in the codepen even though your example here doesn't show it.

How about doing two `.col-6` columns and having the divider be a left border on the right column?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xaeWGB

```
<div class="left">
    <hr class="container hline">
    <div id="main" class="container border">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 top">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 divider top">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```